# Electron and NodeJS is unable to write logs to a file

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am running a nodejs app inside electron. The nodejs app writes logs to a log file that sits in a same installed path of the app.

I then use electron builder to build an installer. On a windows machine when I install the application under `C:\Users\username`, the nodejs app writes logs to the log file without any issue. But the problem arises when the app is installed under `C:\Program Files\MyApp`, the app shows the following error:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program
>   Files\MyApp\resources\app.asar.unpacked\server\logs\output.log'

However if I run the app as an administrator then it works perfectly. This clearly is a permission issue. How do I make my app write to the log in the above mentioned path without any admin privileges?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not provide permission to write to `Program Files` directory unless you have administrator privileges. Either you have to force user to run you program as administrator or write logs to a folder like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\<yourappname>` as most applications does

Answer (score 2):

Its better to store the logs somewhere in

```
path.join(app.getPath('userData'),'logs');
```

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname